# How to execute MATLAB program from PHP?

Tags: php, matlab

I have written a fingerprint verification function in `MATLAB` and want to call this function form `PHP`. Any idea how to do it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some snippet..or tell where you got stuck...so that others can find out the issue

Comment: What do you expect to get back into php, if any? Do you want to pass variables between php and Matlab or do you just want to execute the Matlab code and forget about it? Your question is quite broad

Comment: @kkuilla yea i'm sending path of two images from php to matlab and matlab read images and compares. If success it will return some positive value or it will return 0.